# Configuring JPA to handle HIBERNATE composite-id and key-property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to find the correct way to convert the below (Hibernate) XML to JPA annotations:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<class name="TesTEntry" table="RAW_SCORE">
  <composite-id mapped="false" unsaved-value="undefined">
   <key-property column="SSN" name="ssn" type="string"/>
   <key-property column="SUB_TEST_CD" name="subTestCd" type="string"/>
  </composite-id>
  <property column="TEST_QY" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="testQy" type="java.lang.Short"/>
  <property column="SYS_REC" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="sysRec" type="java.util.Date"/>
  <property column="SYS_ID" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="sysId" type="java.lang.String"/>
 </class>
```

Since I have two `<key-property>` I am not sure if I use `@Id`, or `@EmbeddedId`

Comment: WHAT XML is that? It is not valid JPA orm.xml.

Comment: @BillyFrost I am transferring it into JPA. The class is a database Entity and I am trying to rid of all of this projects XML and use annotations.

Comment: Yes, and WHAT DOES THAT XML MEAN? You don't define what it is from (it certainly isn't from JPA). JPA documentation tells you how to support composite PKs, such as this doc http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/application_identity.html#Multiple_PrimaryKey_field   define multiple Id fields and define an IdClass

Comment: @BillyFrost is it s Hibernate xml file used used for mapping entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since I have two  I am not sure if I use @Id, or @EmbeddedId

You mean probably `IdClass`. And it doesn't matter which one you use.

Let us say, you want to use `@IdClass`:

- Define a class for your ID.
- Implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods
- Implement public default constructor
- Implement the `Serializable` interface

Here is an example implementation (equals & hashCode are generated from IDE):

```
    public class TestEntityPK implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -3424067518791080014L;

       private String ssn;
       private String subTestCd;

       public TestEntityPK() { // }

       public TestEntityPK(String ssn, String subTestCd) {
           this.ssn = ssn;
           this.subTestCd;
       }

       public String getSsn() {
          return ssn;
       }

       public String getSubTestCd() {
          return subTestCd;
       }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          final int prime = 31;
          int result = 1;
          result = prime * result + ((ssn == null) ? 0 : ssn.hashCode());
          result = prime * result
            + ((subTestCd == null) ? 0 : subTestCd.hashCode());
          return result;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          if (this == obj)
              return true;
          if (obj == null)
              return false;
          if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
              return false;
          TestEntityPK other = (TestEntityPK) obj;
          if (ssn == null) {
             if (other.ssn != null)
                 return false;
          } else if (!ssn.equals(other.ssn))
              return false;
          if (subTestCd == null) {
              if (other.subTestCd != null)
                  return false;
           } else if (!subTestCd.equals(other.subTestCd))
              return false;
           return true;
      }
```

}

And use it in the entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RAW_SCORE")
@IdClass(TestEntityPK.class)
public class TestEntity {
    @Id private String ssn;

    @Id 
    @Column(name="SUB_TEST_CD")
    private String subTestCd;

    @Column(name="TEST_QY")
    private short testQy;

    @Column(name="SYS_REC")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date sysRec;

    @Column(name="SYS_ID")
    private String sysId;

    // getters and setters
}
```